# After collapse one div, get full width of another div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

on the web page I have two div, inline. I have a button for collapse left div. How to make another div to full-width size, and again make it smaller when show first div again? 
This is full width (col-lg-4 and col-lg-8)
[image]
and this is when left div is collapsed (on this situation, green div need to have full width size)
[image]

```
"https://jsfiddle.net/q4eotzb0/1/"

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  //This will hide the DIV by default.
  $scope.IsVisible = true;
  $scope.ShowHide = function() {
    //If DIV is visible it will be hidden and vice versa.
    $scope.IsVisible = !$scope.IsVisible;
  }
});

</script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
<input type="button" value="SHOW/HIDE" ng-click="ShowHide()" />
<br />
<br />
<div class="container-fluid col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

<div class="test col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" ng-class="
{'divOpen': IsVisible}">

</div>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
 <div class="testtest"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
.test {
background: red;
width: 250px;
height: 100px;
-webkit-transition: width 2s;-moz-transition: width 2s ease-in-out;-ms-
transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: width 2s ease-in-out;transition: width 2s;
}


.divOpen{
width: 100px;
}
.testtest{
background: green;
height: 100px;
width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Don't just add jsfiddle link. Add the code aswell for futur references.

Comment: `.divOpen {
    width: 0px;
    padding: 0;
} `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this `css` along with yours

```
.divOpen + div{
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

Comment: excellent... Only one thing... this working like I expect, but... when all div is visible and I click on collapse button, red div start transition to a smaller dimension, but green on the second disappear and showing on full size (like I want). When I click again collapse button, transition starts to start position, in this case, green div working normally, without disappearing bug. And pls, can you explain me this CSS calc in this case... Thnx

Comment: you have `transition` `css` to `.test` right. Add that to `.divOpen + div` too

Comment: `-webkit-transition: width 2s;-moz-transition: width 2s ease-in-out;-ms-
transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: width 2s ease-in-out;transition: width 2s;`

Comment: `calc` function will calculate based on the operation specified. Here it is calculating the width of `100% - 100px`

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution using `flex`

```js
$(function() {
  $('[type=button]').on('click', function() {
    $('.red').toggleClass('divOpen');
  });
});
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
.expender {
  display: flex;
  align-content: stretch;
}
.red {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  flex: 1 1 250px;
  -webkit-transition: flex-basis 2s;
  -moz-transition: flex-basis 2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: flex-basis 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: flex-basis 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: flex-basis 2s;
}
.red.divOpen {
  flex-basis: 100px;
}
.green {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  background: green;
  height: 100px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="SHOW/HIDE" />
<div class="expender">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```